# Determining constructor parameter count and type via reflection in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I have about a hundred small classes that inherit a trait.  The classes are instantiated in a factory via reflection based on their names.

```
Class.forName(name).getConstructor().newInstance().asInstanceOf[Trait]
```

Now requirements have changed such that one and only one of the classes needs to take a parameter during construction.  I am trying to change the factory to handle this new case.  The REPL worksheet with my approach looks like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor

trait T {
  def p: Unit
}

class C1 extends T {
  override def p = println("no ymd")
}

class C2(a: Array[String]) extends T {
  override def p = println(s"year: ${a(0)}")
}

class C3(a: Array[Int]) extends T {
  override def p = println(s"day: ${a(2)}")
}

val ymd = Array("2019","10","23")
val ymd_int = Array(2019,10,23)

def getT(c: Class[_]): T = {
  c.getConstructors match {
    case Array(c: Constructor[Array[String]]) => c.newInstance(ymd).asInstanceOf[T]
    case Array(c: Constructor[Array[Int]]) => c.newInstance(ymd_int).asInstanceOf[T]
    case Array(c: Constructor[_]) => c.newInstance().asInstanceOf[T]
    case _ => throw new Exception("...")
  }
}

getT(classOf[C1]).p
getT(classOf[C2]).p
getT(classOf[C3]).p
```

In the REPL, I'm using `classOf` instead of `Class.forName` because class names in the REPL are kind of wonky.

During compilation I'm getting the warnings:

```
Warning:(25, 23) non-variable type argument Array[String] in type
pattern java.lang.reflect.Constructor[Array[String]] is unchecked 
since it is eliminated by erasure 
case Array(c: Constructor[Array[String]]) =>
    c.newInstance(ymd).asInstanceOf[T]
```

and

```
Warning:(26, 23) non-variable type argument Array[Int] in type
pattern java.lang.reflect.Constructor[Array[Int]] is unchecked 
since it is eliminated by erasure
case Array(c: Constructor[Array[Int]]) =>
    c.newInstance(ymd_int).asInstanceOf[T]
```

And then of course the calls to `getT` are failing because the three case statements look identical at run time and so all three calls are being handled by the first case.

Please Help.

Comment: Using reflection is rarely a good idea

Comment: @cchantep you're not wrong, but sometimes you go to work with the system you have, not the system you want.  I'm working with some legacy run-time dependency injection that I have neither the time nor the authority to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
def getT(clazz: Class[_]): T = {
  val constructor = clazz.getConstructors.head
  (constructor.getParameterTypes.headOption.map(_.getSimpleName) match {
    case None             => constructor.newInstance()
    case Some("String[]") => constructor.newInstance(ymd)
    case Some("int[]")    => constructor.newInstance(ymd_int)
    case _                => throw new Exception("...")
  }).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!